# Multi-Column Table Display from one MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, html-table

I have a problem with displaying multiple columns from a MySQL table.
It is fairly simple - I have 28 records, and I want to make 7 rows of 4 - each record is just two columns - id# and name ("handle" in table).

What my problem is that when I use the

```
> $i<$cols
```

I am getting four columns, but the fourth one is blank, and every fourth record is being skipped (#4, #8, etc.) Simple I said...just make it `$row && $i<=$cols` adding the <= conditional to the `$i` variable...but then it just ignores the if statement and displays all the records across the page. 
What am I doing wrong? Do I need another `if` statement wrapped around that one? Not sure where I am going wrong...

Here is where I have gotten so far:

```
// Table header.
echo '<center><table align="center" BLAH BLAH BLAH</b></td></tr><tr>';
do {
  // Fetch and print all the records:
  $cols = 4;
  for($i=1;$i<=$cols;$i++){ 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if($row && $i<$cols){
      echo '<td  align="center" bgcolor="' . '#' . $row['color'] . '"><b>' .
           $row['player_id'] . '</td></b><td  align="left" bgcolor="' . '#' .
           $row['color'] . '"><b>' . strtoupper($row['handle']) . '</td></b>';
    }
    else {
      echo '</tr>';
    }
  }
}              
while ($row);
  echo '</table></center>'; // Close the table.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `echo '</tr>'` outside of the for loop.  Have the do...while loop open and close the `<tr>` tags:

```
// Table header.
echo '<center><table align="center" BLAH BLAH BLAH</b></td></tr>';
do {
  echo '<tr>';
  // Fetch and print all the records:
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  if($row){
    echo '<td  align="center" bgcolor="' . '#' . $row['color'] . '"><b>' .
         $row['player_id'] . '</b></td><td  align="left" bgcolor="' . '#' .
         $row['color'] . '"><b>' . strtoupper($row['handle']) . '</b></td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
} while ($row); echo '</table></center>'; // Close the table.
```

EDIT: just realized you don't need the for loop.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!! I knew it was going to be something easy for one of the geniuses here!

Comment: Also, please note that I changed your tags.  You had <td><b>...</td></b>, which is incorrect syntax; it should be <td><b>...</b></td>.

Comment: Thanks Ivan - I will correct that as well - appreciate your help very much!